# CSS Flexbox - expand container download to show overflow content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I'm trying to figure out how to "expand down" a flex container to show content that is currently being hidden.

I have a small demo showing the issue here:

https://jsfiddle.net/darrengates/d4eqfppw/

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}
```

I've tried various combinations of "flex-shrink" and "flex-grow" but to no effect.

The idea is that I want to keep the top cell as the current size, and only "expand down" the bottom part to show the text which is currently hidden.

Comment: Hi Darren, you need to include the code here on Stack Overflow, not just a link to your site. We shouldn't have to dig through your code, and your site will change with time and this question will be useless to people in the future who have a similar problem, since the they can't reference the original code. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: I'll try to do that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the Chrome inspector, the problem here is that the property `flex: 1;` is causing your containers in your left column to be equal heights. (The top image and the text in this case).

What you need to do is remove the `flex: 1;` property on those child elements and revert them back to the initial state `flex: 0 auto;` or `flex: initial;`, that will get your text container to expand to its full height.

At this stage, you will find that your top image is gone; this is because `flex` requires stuff inside it to determine its height, especially when it is set on `flex-direction: column;`. Previously when it was set to `flex: 1;`, it would determine the height of both containers to be equal to each other, now that you have changed this, you will need to set a `height` on this. This is one of the reasons why using `<img>` is better than using `background-image`.